# More than one tikz block chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm having a problem when I use a tikz block chain in more than a frame. My codes are below:

```
   \documentclass[pdf]{beamer}    
        \mode<presentation>{}
    \usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl






    \usepackage{stmaryrd}
    \usepackage{graphicx}


    \usetheme{Antibes}

    \usecolortheme{beaver}

    \justifying


    \usepackage{parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}


    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red!30,fg=black}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{caption}


    \author{Gabriel Petrini da Silveira \and RA 155468
    \\ \textbf{Orientador:} Antônio Carlos Macedo e Silva \\ \
    {\footnotesize\ttfamily gpetrinidasilveira@gmail.com}}
    \title[Política Fiscal: HPE, Grande Recessão e SFC]{Política Fiscal e(m) Grande Recessão: uma análise com Consistência entre Fluxos e Estoques}
    \institute{Instituto de Economia - UNICAMP}
    \date{05 de Dezembro - 2017}



    \usepackage{multirow}




    \usepackage{framed} 
    \makeindex



    \tikzset{
        basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
        root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
            fill=green!30},
        level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
            text width=8em},
        level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=white, text width=6.5em}
    }

    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \usepackage{arydshln}


    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

 \begin{document}
     \begin{frame}  
    \frametitle{Características do NCM}     

        Neste arcabouço:    
            \begin{description}         
            \item[Principal instrumento] Taxa de
         juros de curto prazo       
             \item[Aparato institucional] Regime de Metas
         para a Inflação        
            \item[Objetivo] Estabilização da inflação
            \end{description}



     \begin{figure}[H]
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = {Latex[]},
        start chain = going right,
        node distance=7mm,
        block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
            inner sep=1mm, align=center,
            minimum height=7mm, on chain}]     %Para que servem esses comandos?
        %placing the blocks
        \node[block] (n1) {Política monetária \\ eficiente};
        \node[block] (n2) {$Y^G$ estável};
        \node[block] (n3) {Inflação estável};
        \node[block] {Nível de \\ atividade};

        \draw[->] (n1.east) --  + (0,0mm) -> (n2.west);
        \draw[->] (n2.east) --  + (0,0mm) -> (n3.west);
        \draw[<->] (n1.south) --  + (0,-7mm) -| (n3.south);
        \draw[<->] (n2.north) --  + (0,+7mm) -| (n3.north);
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{figure}

     \begin{framed}
        Portanto, há uma hierarquia entre os objetivos de política econômica, subordinando os demais ao controle da inflação.
     \end{framed}
     \end{frame}

     \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{SFC e política fiscal}
     \framesubtitle{Estrutura Modelo G\&L}
     \begin{center}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = {Latex[]},
        start chain = going right,
        node distance=7mm,
        block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
            inner sep=1mm, align=center,
            minimum height=7mm, 
            join=by ->, on chain}]     %Para que servem esses comandos?
        %placing the blocks
        \node[block] (n10) {Modelo SFC-PK};
        \node[block] (n11) {Endogenização \\ dos gastos \\ públicos};
        \node[block] (n12) {Função de reação};
     %  \node[block] (n4) {Endogenização \\ dos gastos \\ públicos};
     %  \node[block] (n5) {Função de reação};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        %Fim Fluxograma

        \begin{equation}
        \label{FiscalReac}
        gr_G = gr - \beta_1\cdot \Delta \pi_{-1} - \beta_2\cdot (\pi_{-1} - \pi^T)
        \end{equation}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[
     > = {Latex[]},
     start chain = going right,
     node distance=7mm,
     block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
        inner sep=1mm, align=center,
        minimum height=7mm,  on chain}]     %Para que servem esses comandos?
     %placing the blocks
     \node[block] (n13) {NCM};
     \node[block] (n14) {Função de reação};
     \node[block] (n15) {$\Delta \pi, y$};
     %  \node[block] (n4) {Endogenização \\ dos gastos \\ públicos};
     %  \node[block] (n5) {Função de reação};
     \draw[->] (n13.south) --  + (0,-7mm) -| (n14.south);
     \draw[->] (n14.north) --  + (0,+7mm) -| (n13.north);
     \draw[->] (n14.east) --  + (0,0mm) -> (n15.west);
     \end{tikzpicture}


     \end{center}
     \end{frame} 
    \end{document}
```

[image: Frame with right tikz block chain]

But, when I use this same structure in another frame, it look like this:
[image: Frame with worng tikz block chain]

Sorry for the mess. Its my first question :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I cannot reproduce the problem with your `frames` into a basic `beamer` document. So if you could arrange your code into a complete example that we could esaily test (with frames inside `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`, with a litle bit simplified preamble, ...) we could help you to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems preventing your code from compiling. If you get any error messages in the .log file, you should not look at the broken `.pdf` file but fix these errors instead of worrying how an image looks like.

- `\documentclass{beamer}` -> the option `[pdf]` is not really necessary
- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` - beamer already provides this functionality
- For using `\justifying` you need the package `ragged2e` - this is one of the errors that prevents you file from compiling. However even with including the package, this command makes not much sense in the preamble
- `\usepackage{caption}`: unnecessary in my opinion, as beamer has its own mechanism for captions
- same for `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`
- don't load the same package multiple times, e.g. `tikz,caption`
- don't load tikz libraries multiple times, e.g. `arrows,shapes,trees,positioning,shadows` and only load them in the preamble, not inside of frames. A superposition of these two problems is the cause of another error preventing your code from compiling.
- `\usepackage{float}` does not make any sense in a documentclass that does not have floats. This also means it should be `\begin{figure}` and not `\begin{figure}[H]`
- Your hack to include additional information on the title page will cause problems with the properties of the pdf, you'll see a warning about this in the `.log` file

---

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%    \justifying

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{caption}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red!30,fg=black}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{arydshln}

%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
%\usetikzlibrary{trees}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{caption}


\author{\texorpdfstring{Gabriel Petrini da Silveira \and RA 155468
\\ \textbf{Orientador:} Antônio Carlos Macedo e Silva \\ 
{\footnotesize\ttfamily gpetrinidasilveira@gmail.com}}{Gabriel Petrini da Silveira}}
\title[Política Fiscal: HPE, Grande Recessão e SFC]{Política Fiscal e(m) Grande Recessão: uma análise com Consistência entre Fluxos e Estoques}
\institute{Instituto de Economia - UNICAMP}
\date{05 de Dezembro - 2017}

%\makeindex

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
        fill=green!30},
    level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
        text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=white, text width=6.5em}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Características do NCM}     

Neste arcabouço:
\begin{description}         
    \item[Principal instrumento] Taxa de juros de curto prazo       
    \item[Aparato institucional] Regime de Metas para a Inflação        
    \item[Objetivo] Estabilização da inflação
\end{description}

\begin{figure}%[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = {Latex[]},
    start chain = going right,
    node distance=7mm,
    block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
        inner sep=1mm, align=center,
        minimum height=7mm, on chain}]     %Para que servem esses comandos?
    %placing the blocks
    \node[block] (n1) {Política monetária \\ eficiente};
    \node[block] (n2) {$Y^G$ estável};
    \node[block] (n3) {Inflação estável};
    \node[block] {Nível de \\ atividade};

    \draw[->] (n1.east) --  + (0,0mm) -> (n2.west);
    \draw[->] (n2.east) --  + (0,0mm) -> (n3.west);
    \draw[<->] (n1.south) --  + (0,-7mm) -| (n3.south);
    \draw[<->] (n2.north) --  + (0,+7mm) -| (n3.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{framed}
    Portanto, há uma hierarquia entre os objetivos de política econômica, subordinando os demais ao controle da inflação.
 \end{framed}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{SFC e política fiscal}
\framesubtitle{Estrutura Modelo G\&L}
 \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = {Latex[]},
    start chain = going right,
    node distance=7mm,
    block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
        inner sep=1mm, align=center,
        minimum height=7mm, 
        join=by ->, on chain}]     %Para que servem esses comandos?
    %placing the blocks
    \node[block] (n10) {Modelo SFC-PK};
    \node[block] (n11) {Endogenização \\ dos gastos \\ públicos};
    \node[block] (n12) {Função de reação};
 %  \node[block] (n4) {Endogenização \\ dos gastos \\ públicos};
 %  \node[block] (n5) {Função de reação};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %Fim Fluxograma

    \begin{equation}
    \label{FiscalReac}
    gr_G = gr - \beta_1\cdot \Delta \pi_{-1} - \beta_2\cdot (\pi_{-1} - \pi^T)
    \end{equation}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 > = {Latex[]},
 start chain = going right,
 node distance=7mm,
 block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
    inner sep=1mm, align=center,
    minimum height=7mm,  on chain}]     %Para que servem esses comandos?
 %placing the blocks
 \node[block] (n13) {NCM};
 \node[block] (n14) {Função de reação};
 \node[block] (n15) {$\Delta \pi, y$};
 %  \node[block] (n4) {Endogenização \\ dos gastos \\ públicos};
 %  \node[block] (n5) {Função de reação};
 \draw[->] (n13.south) --  + (0,-7mm) -| (n14.south);
 \draw[->] (n14.north) --  + (0,+7mm) -| (n13.north);
 \draw[->] (n14.east) --  + (0,0mm) -> (n15.west);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @GabrielPetrinidaSilveira, if answer solve your problem, than consider accept it (click check mark at upper left corner of answer) :-)